# Java Survivor1, Survivor2 in VM Survivor Old Gen

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm, java-8

I thought, that in Java-Heap-Memory model

- Survivor and
- Old Gen

are synonymous. That it would be the area, where Java puts Object, which survived some GC Cycles.
In VisualVM I see, that these are two different areas and that even there are multiple Survivor areas.

What is the difference between Survivor and Old Gen areas in java memory?[image]

**EDIT:**

It seems, that **Survivor** (together with Eden) belongs to **Young Gen**,
See
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two survivor areas, S0 and S1. At any time, one of them are the *from space* or *to space*.

When a Minor GC happens, it collects objects from Eden space and the survivors are placed in the *to space*.

Objects from the previous GC, which are in the *from space* are also moved to the *to space*, unless they've reached a survivor threshold, which means this object is a long living object. In this case it is *promoted* to the Old Generation instead.

After this, the survivor spaces are swapped, so the *to space* is always clear.

There are only two survivor spaces. In the image, the *Spaces* and *Graphs* areas are just different representations of the same information.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).